# Android Debugging, how?

Tags: android

Ok so I've finally cobbled enough working parts into my app that its just plain old refusing to do anything now. I understand how to use logcat, but that is about it.

The main problem at the moment is that I get the error

> Activity Idle Timeout for HistoryRecord then my package

I need to learn how to do better debugging. Plus if anyone can suggest things I should do for this error please let me know.
I think its something to do with the interactions with the database.

Cheers

EDIT:

> What IDE are you using, if any?
>   Eclipse with Android tool has
>   moderately good debugging facilities;
>   set a breakpoint and debug away.

I am using Eclipse
And I know of breakpoints, but not their real use. Where would I set them for this error?

I am used to PHP where errors tell you a specific line to look at is there a way to do this in Eclipse?

Comment: What IDE are you using, if any? Eclipse with Android tool has moderately good debugging facilities; set a breakpoint and debug away.

Comment: @Seva Aleseyev Edited main post to answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that the debugger can help much in this case. Probably some component (services, receivers...) is blocking the main thread with some long running operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse if you right click in the margin next to your code - easy place to start is probably in your `onCreate` method - you can choose to *Toggle Breakpoint*.  This will set a breakpoint at that location.

Now, in Eclipse choose Run->Debug As->Android Application.

This will run your app in the emulator and your app with stop running at your breakpoint.  At this point you can step thru your code line by line using F6 I believe.

Once you've hit the breakpoint and your code is paused, use a guide like this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/ which will highlight all the different things you can do at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Max... If you can wrap the offending line of code in try catch you can log the exception or set a breakpoint at the exception. So for the code below that will throw an exception:

```
String test= null;
try {
 test.length();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG,"test",e);
}
```

LogCat will display test,java.lang.NullPointerException blah, blah, blah

OR you can set a breakpoint at the Log.d line and if hit in DEBUG mode the app will pause and the variable window in the DEBUG view will show:

```
this:MyApp e:NullPointerException
```

BUT it does not sound like your app is throwing an exception, rather it is timing out on a database call. I would stub out the call to the database and see if the timeout goes away. Then slowly add back code until it times out.

JAL